# Atomicity of a job execution in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, atomic

I would like to find the proper documentation to confirm my thought about a SQL Server job I recently wrote. My fear is that data could be inconsistent for few milliseconds (timing between the start of the job execution and its end).

Let's say the job is setup to run every 30 minutes. It will only have one step with the following SQL statement:

```
DELETE FROM myTable

INSERT INTO myTable 
    SELECT * 
    FROM myTableTemp
```

Could it happens that a `SELECT` query would be executed exactly in between the `DELETE` statement and the `INSERT` statement and thus returning empty results?

And what if I would have created 2 steps in my job, one for the `DELETE` query and another for the `INSERT INTO`? Is the atomicity is protected by SQL Server between several steps of one job?

Thanks for your help on this one

Comment: Look into Transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no automatic atomic handling of jobs, whether they are multiple statements or steps.

Use this:

```
begin transaction
delete...
insert....
... anything else you need to be atomic
commit work
```

Comment: Yes it does @marc_s because the transaction means no-one else will see the delete till the transaction completes. In this case other users would be blocked if they tried to read the same rows.

Comment: Thank for this answer; could you also tell me what would happen in case of the `SELECT` within the transaction is taking 10 sec to execute (for whatever reason)? Does `myTable` would be locked to any read for more than 10 seconds also? If yes, is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Sql Server will use the appropriate level of lock. So if you have a million records it won't lock the whole table. There is a sequence of internally managed escalations of lock levels sql server will use so that the smallest number of others could be affected, balanced with efficiency. Eventually, if you are affecting enough rows then it will lock the entire table (which you may see if you test with a very small table in the first place) but in practical sense thats not a worry. It is good practice to try and keep whats inside your transaction as short as you need to to reduce contention.